# Iso 3 letter country code validation in JAVA

Tags: java, validation

Using Java, is there a way to check if a given string is a valid ISO 3 letter country code?
(example: check if USA is correct or not)

If possible, please provide a solution without having to make country code map.

Comment: Why no Map? Seems like a useful data structure for this problem.

Answer (score 8):

Since Java 9 you can use [`Locale::getISOCountries`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#getISOCountries-java.util.Locale.IsoCountryCode-) method, passing a flag for the 3-letter kind, [`Locale.IsoCountryCode.PART1_ALPHA3`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.IsoCountryCode.html#PART1_ALPHA3).

```
boolean contains = Locale.getISOCountries(Locale.IsoCountryCode.PART1_ALPHA3).contains("USA");
```

Comment: My bad, am using JAVA 8

Answer (score 4):

You can use both the `Locale.getISOCountries()` and `Locale.getISO3Country()` methods contained within the `Locale` class to get all the three letter country codes. Here is a method that will return a `String[]` array of all the three letter country codes:

```
public static String[] getISO3CountryCodes() {
    String[] countries = Locale.getISOCountries();
    String[] iso3 = new String[countries.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        Locale locale = new Locale("", countries[i]);
        iso3[i] = locale.getISO3Country();
    }
    return iso3;
}
```

And to fire it up with a validation example:

```
// Get the Country Codes and place them into a Collection (List Interface)
List<String> countryCodes = java.util.Arrays.asList(getISO3CountryCodes());
System.out.println(countryCodes);  //Display the collection in Console

// Get Country Code input from User and test for validity.
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String cCode = "";
while (cCode.equals("")) {
    System.out.print("Enter a Country code: --> ");
    cCode = input.nextLine().trim().toUpperCase();
    // Is the supplied Country Code contained within the
    // List. If not then it's invalid.
    if (!countryCodes.contains(cCode)) {
        // Nope...supplied country code is not in the List. 
        System.err.println("Invalid Country Code Supplied (" + cCode + ")!");
        System.out.println();
        cCode = "";  // Null String to ensure re-prompting
    }
}
System.out.println("Valid Country Code Supplied (" + cCode + "). Thank-You");
```